Can we prove Young's Convolution Inequality only using Interpolation?
I tried to prove Young's Convolution Inequality $\|f\ast g\|_r\leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$ for $1/r+1=1/p+1/q$, where $p,q,r\in[1,\infty]$. From the Riesz–Thorin Interpolation theorem, it suffices to prove for $r=q,p=1$ and some endpoints.
Is it possible to achieve $\|f\ast g\|_p\leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_p$ by interpolation? I tried (and failed) to prove $C\colon X\to\mathcal{B}(L_1,L_p), f\mapsto C_f$ is bounded, where $X=(L_1 \cap L_\infty, \| \ \|_p)$ and $C_f(g):=f\ast g$.
Though Minkowski's Integral Inequality and boundedness of Intergral Kernel operator work, is such a different approach possible?

Once you show that $|fg|_1\le |f|_1|g|_1$ and $|fg|_\infty \le |f|1|g|\infty$ then you may apply the Riesz-Thorin theorem and get the conclusion. The second inequality is straightforward while the first one reduces to the Fubini theorem

@RyszardSzwarc: Thanks for your comment! I think I have got the point
